# Why does this for loop create a black empty rectangle in between

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
- (void)addBackground{
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    float maxReach = 0;

    //Loop 3 times
    for (int loopTimes = 0; loopTimes < 2; loopTimes++) {

    //Add images to batchNode
    for (int imageNumber=1; imageNumber < 13; imageNumber++) {
            CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"national_scenery_part%d.png",imageNumber]];
            background.position = ccp((winSize.width/2)+maxReach, winSize.height/2);
            [self addChild:background z:0];
            maxReach = maxReach + background.contentSize.width;
    }
    //Ends loopTimes loop
    }
}
```

Image **# 7** shows up as a slender rectangle about **1/4** its original size.

Comment: Half-open intervals are great because you can use `i < begin + length`. Don't write `i < begin + length - 1`, it's too little.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that..pls clarify

Answer (score 2):

Your outer for-loop claims to loop 3 times, but as written will only execute twice. Is that what you want?

Comment: In trying to avoid an off-by-one error, an off-by-one error is introduced. Ain't that just the way?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to decide if I should loop it 2 or 3 times.  I set it to 2 because I don't want to have to go thru all 3 times before seeing the end result.  But the problem is that for some reason the 7th image gets cut off...overlapped by the 8th one I guess

Answer (score 0):

My bad...images 9-13 were 2048 instead of 1024.